# geolocation does not work in simple js

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
document.querySelector("#posBtn").addEventListener("click", function () { navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(PositionFunction); });

function PositionFunction(p) {

    console.log(p.coords.longitude);
}
```

It Seems so simple, but it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: add a error callback function to debug it. refer to it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working just fine! what you would be getting is a warning that GeoLocation is not supported on HTTP anymore you need HTTPS for it to work.

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

```js
document.querySelector("#posBtn").addEventListener("click", function () { navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(PositionFunction); });

function PositionFunction(p) {

    console.log(p.coords.longitude);
}
```

```html
<button id="posBtn">
Get Longitude
</button>
```

More details [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only)

Here's the working [example of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/v3nxf0ub/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to capture the error, to know why its not working

```
document.querySelector("#posBtn").addEventListener("click",function(){
         if (navigator.geolocation) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(PositionFunction, showError);
          } else {
              console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
          }

      });

      function PositionFunction(p) {
         console.log(p.coords.longitude);
      };

      function showError(error) {
        switch(error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                console.log("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                console.log("Location information is unavailable.");
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                console.log("The request to get user location timed out.");
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                console.log("An unknown error occurred.");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Check out the working example : https://jsfiddle.net/ozmsq23w/6/